# Parse a complex JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa

I stumbled into a problem at work. I have a certain JSON I need to parse so I can populate my table. But lets ignore the table population since I can do that myself. What I seem to have problem with is parsing this big json. On short:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray* DetaliiTehnice = [json objectForKey:@"DetaliiTehnice"]; //10 elements
NSArray* ExtraData = [json objectForKey:@"ExtraData"]; //2 keys
```

I didn't managed to parse them more. From the complete parse I want to have this:

```
- Array DateTehnice (10 elements)
     + Array/String Denumire (1 element)
     + Array Valori (3 elements)
         + String Criteriu
         + String Prod1
         + String Prod2

- Array ExtraData (6 elements)
     + Array/String Denumire (1 element)
     + Array Valori (3 elements)
         + String Criteriu
         + String Prod1
         + String Prod2
```

The one marked with + are the one I really need. I don't know how to access them. How can I acces Prod2 value? I don't need something very optimize, I just need a solution from which I can access the elements.

Comment: Can you post the JSON, since this will give us more information about the structure.

Comment: What data your tableView need from DateTehnice or ExtraData?

Comment: I posted the link to the JSON, check the first line of code I posted. It's on the website. I need both arrays, DateTehnice contains the strings with the information the client will look for (e.g: eggs, milk, bread) and ExtraData contains the link to pictures for the information I display (e.g: link to the egg image).

Comment: What type of data do you get from url - array or dictionary? Maybe you need  NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error]; ?

Comment: You can try JSON Accelerator tool. this is very easy and useful tool to create Bean class of JSON response. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/json-accelerator/id511324989?mt=12. I think this tool help you to parse json easily. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *prod2_DateTehnice = [[[json objectForKey:@"DateTehnice"]objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:2];
```

Same way

```
NSString *prod2_ExtraData = [[[json objectForKey:@"ExtraData"]objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: Check your json then, if it has values. NSlog(@"json Data %@",json);

Answer (score 0):

If you get dictionary from server, get data so:

```
NSArray *DetaliiTehnice = json[@"DateTehnice"];
for (NSString *item in DetaliiTehnice) {
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
}
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%@", DetaliiTehnice[1]);
```

If you get array, then replace to:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict = json[1]; //change index
NSArray *DetaliiTehnice = dict[@"DateTehnice"];
for (NSString *item in DetaliiTehnice) {
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
}
```